# Error en Plugin Media en Xamarin forms al abrir la camara en android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos tengo un problema en xamarin forms con el plugin de media, he realizado la configuración adecuada según readme.txt del plugin y configuraciones buscadas en internet el problema que tengo es que en el emulador y celulares Samsung si funciona abrir la cámara, pero con un huawei y6 2019 android version 9 , no me funciona ni con otros huawei no se si el recurso se debe de especificar diferente para esta marca o me falta algun detalle, y he realizado una aplicación limpia que solo tenga ese plugin y el mainpage normal con un boton que abra la camara para realizar las pruebas.

El error es:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file. Please check documentation on how to set this up in your project.'
```

Tengo creado el XML en resources creando una carpeta llamada xml con el archivo
file_paths.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

y en Android manifest ya he especificado:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>


</provider>
```

En el MainActivity tengo configurado:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{

    Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola la solución a este problema lo trate realizando lo siguiente.

En la carpeta  xml con el archivo file_paths.xml, se modifico

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images"  path="Pictures"/>
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />


  <external-path name="external" path="." />
  <root-path name="root" path="." />



</paths>
```

Me ha funcionado tanto con el "External" o "root" pero dejo las dos para que mas de alguna persona le pueda servir cabe resaltar que esta parte es porque algunos modelos de celulares tiene diferente nombres de archivo raíz por lo tanto esta ha sido la solución que a mi me ha funcionado.